# Continuous ticking sounds coming from the system speaker with no display

Tags: motherboard

My PC has an issue that I can't make sense of, even after doing some troubleshooting on my end and pinpointing that the culprit is the motherboard. I shut my PC down one night, everything normal, absolutely no issues or crashing. The other day I turn it on and it gives no display, no POST at all. I leaned towards the PC to discover their were continuous "tick, tick" sounds coming from it at about 1 second intervals. So I decided to start troubleshooting.

One by one and turning on the PC to check after disconnecting every peripheral, I took out the GPU, disconnected HDDs, removed RAM and installed the two sticks one at a time, nothing made a difference to the ticking. At that point I thought it was the PSU but all the system fans were spinning despite the ticking. To confirm I disconnected the system speaker and turned on the system. The ticking sounds stopped and there was still no display. So that's how I know this is a motherboard issue. My question is, what's causing it?

I'm listing my specs down below:
Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-H81M-DS2
Processor: Core i5-4440 @ 3.0GHz
GPU: Asus GTX 770
PSU: OCZ StealthXStream 600W
RAM: 16GB (8GB x 2 sticks)
HDD: 2TB + 1TB (Disconnected both, I can confirm the ticking sound is NOT coming from the HDDs. Only the system speaker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The case was shorting the motherboard due to contact. My case was really old so I just changed the case, but reseating the motherboard might work too.

Answer (score 1):

There's tons of components on your motherboard and it's possible for any one of them to fail and give you your experienced issue.

The only way to truly narrow it down from this point to to replace your CPU with a know working and compatible one and see if that works. Also, it's possible that the PSU is causing this so I'd recommend swapping it too, with a known compatible PSU.

I'm not sure if anyone can tell you which exact component on your motherboard is causing the issue (since you've already ruled out RAM, GFX card, and Storage). But if the only three items remain are your PSU, motherboard, and CPU, then swapping one out for a good one is the only way to troubleshoot any further.

Comment: If it was the CPU, wouldn't the motherboard give me a POST code instead of no POST code at all and instead keep ticking? I looked it up, CPU issues POST code for my motherboard is 5 short beeps. I'm getting no beeps, only ticking. I'll try replacing the PSU and test.

Comment: Not necessarily. Post codes don't always work and don't always work like you'd expect them to. If you don't have any spare parts to troubleshoot with, you can buy a replacement motherboard as that's most likely the culprit. Just try and get one locally if you can so you can return it if that's not the cause.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a spare CPU, though I checked with my spare PSU and it didn't make a difference so I agree with you that motherboard is looking like the likely culprit. I'll replace it and update here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The last time I had issues like this was when I had a computer plugged directly into the wall. A power surge had cooked the motherboard, leaving dark rings around the incoming power connector pins (where they connected to the board).

Comment: Hey Justin, that's what I suspected at first too but power surge and/or outage is not a factor here. The PC is plugged into a UPS with both backup and surge protection. There are no visible burns on the motherboard at all.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the RAM sticks. Replacement helped.